# Passing Array of String as Argument to Function

Tags: c

I am trying to pass an array of strings to a function and then the print it there. But it is giving segmentation fault.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            scanf("%s",(str+i));
    }
    display(str);
}

void display(char **p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            printf("%s \n",p[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do **not** allocate any memory for the strings.

Comment: There are no "strings" defined in the code you show. In fact C does not know a data type "string". There are different ways to allocate memory to be used like an array of "string" in C. You do not show which you intent to use. The way to pass an array of "string" to a function depends on how it was allocated. Due to all this your question as it stands cannot be answered.

Comment: `str[i]=malloc(100); scanf("%s", str[i]);`

Comment: Use that inside `for` loop

Comment: I am taking input fro user and want to pass that array of string to function and then print it. 
Expected Result:
Input:
String1
String2
Output:
String1
String2

Actual Result:
Input:
String1
String2
Output:
Segmentation Fault

Comment: @EsmaeelE: ... but use `scanf("%99s", str[i]);` when allocating 100 `char` to `str[i]` to avoid a possible buffer overflow when scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not allocating memory for your list. Here is a sample code that i made.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define LIST_SIZE 2
#define MAX_WORD 100

void display(char**);

int main() {
    char buffer[100];
    char** list;
    int i;
    int n;

    // allocate
    list = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * LIST_SIZE);

    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        scanf("%99s",buffer);
        n = strlen(buffer);
        list[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        strcpy(list[i], buffer);
    }

    display(list);

    return 0;
}

void display(char** str) {
    int i;
    printf("-- output ---\n");
    for(i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
}
```

I made the list only allocate the space necessary for the word. If you want fixed you dont need a buffer and the strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to make the following change in the "display" function ....

```
printf("%s \n",p+i);
```

In addition, the "display" function needs to be placed above "main" or you need to declare a prototype for the function.